# javascript if if else logic

Tags: javascript, date

There is some sort of logic error in my code, but I'm not sure where.

1. When the elapsed time goes from `00:07:59` to `00:08:00`, the color switches back from yellow, which happens at `00:05:00`.
2. At `00:10:00` it turns from gray to red.

Something in my logic allows any time between `00:08:00` and `00:09:59` to satisfy the first condition which is to be less than 5.

```
   if (parseInt(this.minutes) < 5) {
       fontColor = "<Font class=\"Gray\">";
   } else if (parseInt(this.minutes) >= 5 && parseInt(this.minutes) < 10){
       fontColor = "<Font class=\"Yellow\">";
   } else {
       fontColor = "<Font class=\"Red\">";
   }
```

Comment: `<font>` tags? Have we gone back to the 90s? `<font>` is depricated in HTML 4.1 and greater. Use `<span>` instead.

Comment: btw, <font> tags are deprecated. You'd better of using CSS.

Comment: did you try console.log(this.minutes) or alerting out alert(this.minutes) to make sure where you stand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature (not a bug!) in parseInt.

When the string starts with a 0, it parses it in Octals (base 8), instead of Decimals (base 10).
just pass a second parameter of 10, and it will use that base for parsing.

```
if (parseInt(this.minutes, 10) < 5) {
    fontColor = "<Font class=\"Gray\">";
} else if (parseInt(this.minutes, 10) >= 5 && parseInt(this.minutes, 10) < 10) {
    fontColor = "<Font class=\"Yellow\">";
} else {
    fontColor = "<Font class=\"Red\">";
}
```

Comment: well, I wouldn't call it a feature either.. :p

Answer (score 2):

Even without knowing what is stored in `this.minutes`, my guess is that you get in trouble because of the missing `radix` value for `parseInt()`.

Since you mentioned you got numbers starting with `0` this is very likely because parseInt assumes those as octal values.

So easy solution, set the radix to `10` to specify a decimal value:

```
if (parseInt(this.minutes, 10) < 5) {
}
```